# как отключить или включить загрузку изображений webview Через checkbox?

Tags: android, webview

как отключить или включить загрузку изображений webview Через checkbox?
такой код у меня не работает(примерно такой) картинки остаются при любом положении checkbox.

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {
    private WebView mWebView; 
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

```
//инициализация переменной boolean для передачи в функцию
public boolean state;

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
{
     @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith(vocnufturl_for_check)) {
                return false;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
}


@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
    boolean isChecked = settings.getBoolean("checkbox", false);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_check);
    item.setChecked(isChecked);

    return true;
  }




        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                   case R.id.action_check:
                    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("checkbox", item.isChecked());
                    editor.commit();
                   /*изменение переменной boolean*/
                    if (item.isChecked()) {
                        state=true;

                    } else {
                        state=false;

                    }
                    return true;

            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


 mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
 WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
 settings.setTextZoom(85); 
 WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
 mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
 mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);


 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

 mWebView.loadUrl(http://vocnuft.volyn.ua);


 /*передача переменной boolean*/
 webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(state);
 webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
 webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(false);
 webSettings.setNeedInitialFocus(false);
 webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
 mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
 mWebView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

В `onOptionsItemSelected` нужно добавить изменение настройки `WebSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(state);` ведь `WebView` сама не догадается, что флаг `state` изменился

Comment: если я добавляю mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(state); в checbox то ничего не меняется при его изменении и даже при пересоздании активити, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: а нет, отключаются изображения просто уже загруженные остаются.

Comment: Метод влияет на загрузку, но не на отображение. Всё что уже попало в кэш будет показано